# Reading a file function only returns first line in file after applying try/except, but program worked as intended without it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so my problem is that i need to define a function that reads a file of numbers (assume everything in the file is a number) and then print any odd number that isn't divisible by 3. My professor asked specifically for try/except in this program.
my code is

```
import sys

def threething(name):
    try:
        file = open(name, 'r')
    except:
        sys.exit("Bad file name for some odd reason idk.")
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        o = int(line)
        if o % 2 == 1:
            if o % 3 != 0:
                return o
    file.close()
filename = input("file name pls: ")
print(threething(filename))
```

and the text file im using just has

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

in it. Before my code worked fine without the try/except and printed 1, 5 and 7 like it's supposed to but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work with try/except.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the `try`/`except` statement has anything to do with the change of behavior. My bet is that, as @theausome noted, you replaced `print(o)` with `return o` without noticing.

The problem is, the `return` statement interrupts the execution of a function. As a simplified example, consider the code below:

```
def f():
    print("returning 1")
    return 1
    print("returning 2")
    return 2
    print("returning 3")
    return 3

print(f())
```

If you call it, you will get this output:

```
returning 1
1
```

Why it only executed the first `print()` of the function? Because after a return, a function stops executing. So, when you returned, the other values were not checked, only the first one was given to the `print` function.

Try to use `print(o)` instead of `return o`. In this case, you will not need to print the return of `threething()`:

```
import sys

def threething(name):
    try:
        file = open(name, 'r')
    except:
        sys.exit("Bad file name for some odd reason idk.")
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        o = int(line)
        if o % 2 == 1:
            if o % 3 != 0:
                print(o)
    file.close()
filename = input("file name pls: ")
threething(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked perfectly. Although I still don't understand why with the "return o" and "print(threething(filename))" way i wrote the program only gave me the first line in the text file. And yeah you're right i did return o without thinking :p

Comment: @JosephLastname it can be confusing in the beginning, indeed! I added a bit more of content to my answer, I hope it helps you understand it a bit more.

Comment: thanks a lot, that helped me understand what I didn't get and it honestly just cleared up a ton of stuff I was having trouble with.